# Lost the color dots on browser's window control buttons

Tags: ui

I lost the color dots on my browser's windows on the top left, now they are all black. How do I change them back to red, yellow and green?

Comment: Please add the name of the browser and a screenshot!

Answer (score 2):

You should go to System Preferences > General and switch the Appearance setting back to Blue from Graphite:

[image]

Blue:

[image]

Graphite:

[image]